# how to search for directories ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to know how to check if a directory exists in my application

for example: if I want to search if a folder exists in my application document

and how to create a new folder within it

best regards

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Checking for file existence:

```
+(BOOL)fileExistsAtAbsolutePath:(NSString*)filename {
    BOOL isDirectory;
    BOOL fileExistsAtPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filename isDirectory:&isDirectory];

    return fileExistsAtPath && !isDirectory;
}
```

Checking for directory existence:

```
+(BOOL)directoryExistsAtAbsolutePath:(NSString*)filename {
    BOOL isDirectory;
    BOOL fileExistsAtPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filename isDirectory:&isDirectory];

    return fileExistsAtPath && isDirectory;
}
```