# Downloading files in two different folders ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, download, asihttprequest

i have an iphone application, that downloads pdf file using a JSON file the JSON response looks like that

```
{
    "resource_id":"1132",
    "name_en":"mpla mpla mpla",
    "name_cn":null,
    "product_id":"1064",
    "product":"mpla",
    "category":"mpla Literature",
    "fileURLString_en":"http://mpla.mpla.com/media/427/mpla.pdf",
    "fileURLString_en_date":"Mon, 03 Sep 2012 08:53:40 GMT",
    "fileURLString_cn":"http://mpla.mpla.com/media/427/mpla.pdf",
    "fileURLString_cn_date":"Mon, 03 Sep 2012 08:53:40 GMT",
    "thumbnailURLString_en":"http://mpla.mpla.com/media/1472/mpla.png",
    "emailURLString_en":null,
    "emailURLString_en_date":null,
    "descriptionString_en":null,
    "emailThumbnailURLString_en":null,
    "emailThumbnailURLString_en_date":null,
    "externalUrl":null
},
```

and i want to download the en files on Library/Caches/en folder and the Chinese files on the Library/Cashes/ch folder.

i'm using ASIHTTPRequest for the communication part! What are your suggestion (in code) for downloading and saving the files an the particular folders?

here is my code so far:

```
        -(void)createDirectory:(NSString *)directoryName atFilePath:(NSString *)filePath
        {
    NSString *filePathAndDirectory = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryName];
    NSLog(@"%@",filePathAndDirectory);
    NSError *error;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                    attributes:nil
                                                         error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
    }
    }



NSString* filePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

        NSString *clanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

        if([clanguage isEqualToString:@"en"])
        {
            NSString *cachesPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
            filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/en/%@",cachesPath,urlPath.lastObject];
        }
        else if([clanguage isEqualToString:@"zh-Hans"])
        {
            NSString *cachesPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
            filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/cn/%@",cachesPath,urlPath.lastObject];

        }
```

i have tried creating two subfolders but can't save the files in them depending on the link.
I also tried renaming the files in name for english and ch_name for chinese but that is not convenient!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but [ASIHTTPRequest has been retired](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"en/mpla.pdf"]]) {
    [downloadedPdfData writeToFile:cachePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

}
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ch/mpla.pdf"]]) {
    [downloadedPdfData writeToFile:cachePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
}
```

Check directory or files exists from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174708/1106035)